# Reaching system behind router

Tags: networking, routing

I have a situation where I have a small server appliance that I want people to be able to just plug into their router, turn it on and let it work. When the appliance starts up it determines its lan address, say: 192.168.1.4 and its public address, say 4.3.2.1. It then sets up a daemon that listens on port 3000. I then will be sending messages to that port from the mothership.

My question is: can this be done without requiring the user to configure port forwarding on their router. They may have N computers behind the router but the appliance is the only one that will be listening on this port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, you can do this using something called [Universal Plug and Play (UPnP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play). In practice, it's turned off by default on most equipment, up to and including home routers, and most competent network administrators leave it that way.

You'll likely need for your appliance poll a command and control service on a network that you control, or set up a proxy service on a network you control such that your appliance can automatically create a vpn/proxy connection such that you can open and forward traffic on the appropriate port.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I'm not quite sure how to set that VPN up.

Comment: It's not something that just exists. This is infrastructure you'll have to build and host somewhere.

Comment: Understood. My comment really meant where do I start? Is it installing openvpn? Then connecting to it via the appliance? Not sure that would work since the appliance is a passive listener. The clients will not be using VPN to talk to it since I don't control the clients.  They just want to send a message to port 3000 and get a response.

Comment: It means you're going to need to redesign part of the application that runs on the appliance, and the service that talks to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your appliance need to support IPv6. There might only be a small percentage of IPv6 users today. But if you expect those appliances to be used for five years before being scraped, then you can expect them to handle more IPv6 traffic in their lifetime than IPv4 traffic.

Any real solution to your challenge involves IPv6. Everything else is just a workaround.

The two workarounds I can come up with for you are UPnP (as mentioned in the [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/702098/214507) by Joel) and an IPv6 tunnel.

The IPv6 tunnel can either send all traffic through a service hosted by you (if you want to be in control of the reliability) or make use of the Teredo protocol and third party relays (but availability of Teredo relays is very poor).

If you do run traffic through a service hosted by you, that service can perform other operations than just tunneling. For example if the traffic is HTTP adding a name based proxy to your hosted service might offer a huge advantage.